# How I change text in UIPickerView from left to right

Tags: iphone

How I can change text in UIPickerView from leftside  to rightsid.

for example if we suggest this is pickerview. I mean the text start from right side.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `titleForRow` delegate method of your picker view you should use `viewForRow`- that way you can return a UILabel that uses right justified text. If you just use the `titleForRow` method you don't have any control over how the text display, but if you use the latter you can customise it to your heart's content.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaankx so much Igot it.Really I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

@lxt answer is right, but if he/she excuse me I'll put the full code

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
  UILabel *lblPickerTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 30)] autorelease];
  lblPickerTitle.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
  lblPickerTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
  lblPickerTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
  return lblPickerTitle;
}
```